# Android Room Entities: Is it possible to ignore fields by default?

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations, android-room

By default, Room creates a column for each field that is defined in the entity. If an entity has fields that I don't want to persist, I have to use the @Ignore annotation.

This poses a problem with inheritance. Annotating all the unwanted fields from a base class becomes unfeasible at a certain point, especially if you have to make your own versions of complex stock objects only to ignore the fields.

Currently, I am using interfaces instead of inheritance to work around that problem, but I would prefer to have a base class for my Room objects.

Do you know a way to ignore fields by default, so I can rather De-Ignore the desired fields instead of the other way around? Preferably in Kotlin?

Edit:
I want to build a treeview of different room entities and it would be nice to have my treeview item as a base class for all of them. But the treeview item implements a lot of stuff, it is not practical to customize all of that just for @Ignore tags. There are workarounds, but i would need less code if i do it this way.

Comment: what is the function is the base class? for that situation, the base class should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Ignore on your base classes as well, for instance:

```
open class MyBaseClass{
    @Ignore
    open var somethingBasic: Int = 0
}

@Entity(...)
class A : MyBaseClass{
    var name: String? = null
}

@Entity(...)
class B : MyBaseClass{
    var type: Int = 0
}
```

But be careful about this because using a base class for different tables is a bit abnormal and it's able to break all your tables somewhere (take migrations as an example). I suggest to take a deeper look on your structure and try to stay away from this :D